# Controller inside MVC architechture

Tags: struts

I want to know about the controller in struts MVC architecture. Does struts-conf.xml file is a controller. I know that it is a part of controller, but someone is saying that it is a controller and at what extend it is true. Please explain it.

Thanks
Vinay

Answer (score 1):

Struts uses the front controller pattern (struts controller) and the command pattern (actions). Strut-config is a configuration file, not a controller, you use that file to configure the struts controller and the whole mvc framework.

Answer (score 0):

In Struts 2 the model, view and controller are implemented by the action, result and FilterDispatcher respectively.

The controller's job is to map the user request to appropriate action.

In Struts 2 FilterDispatcher does the job of Controller.

Model contains the data and the business logic.

In Struts 2 the model is implemented by the Action component.

View is the presentation component of the MVC Pattern.

curtosy: http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-tutorial/struts-2-framework-tutorial-1.html